# PowerShell move-item to same subfolder name within folders structure

Tags: powershell, file-transfer

I have folder c:\tmp with a bunch of subfolders e:\tmp\2044998 filled with pdf files. I would like to organize all files in the subfolders containing word 2019 to existing folder e:\tmp*\2019. Meaning - locate all *2019*.pdf and move to e:\tmp*\2019.

I don't know syntax for moving files to destination.

What can be the working syntax?

```
dir E:\tmp*\* -Recurse | where {($_.extension -eq '.pdf' -and $_ -like '*2019*')} | move-item -Destination
```

Comment: There's no destination path in your code. Add a destination path and it should work fine. `dir E:\tmp*\* -Recurse | where {($_.extension -eq '.pdf' -and $_ -like '*2019*')} | move-item -Destination "C:\DestinationDir"`

Comment: This portion of your questioni is unclear: "...`to existing folder e:\tmp*\2019.`". You can't have '*' as part of a literal path. Is your destination a single folder or a servies of folders?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Filter` parameter instead of `Where-Object` here for much more efficient code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\tmp' -Filter '*2019*.pdf' -Recurse |
Move-Item -Destination 'E:\tmp\2019'
```

Comment: When `Path` is a single string as opposed to an array, you can combine it with your `Filter` parameter: `Get-ChildItem E:\temp\*2019*.pdf -Recurse | ...`

Answer (score 0):

When you cross-post the same question to multiple sites, you should let folks know.
I replied to you in your other site posting yesterday, with an answer, further explanation and sample working demo code.

[powershell move-item to same subfolder name within folders structure](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/71530/powershell-move-item-to-same-subfolder-name-within-folders-structure)

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, here is the working script:

$Files = get-childitem -path "c:\tmp" -recurse -file | where-object {$_.Name -like "*2019*.pdf"}
Foreach ($file in $files){
    new-item -itemType Directory -path $file.DirectoryName -name 2019 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    move-item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$($file.DirectoryName)\2019\"
}